# Opposite of ‘Irredeemable’ in Describing a Trait

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

I am helping a friend write a recommendation letter.

To me, he has one trait - tenacity - that makes him an excellent worker for his industry, as once he latches onto a problem, he persists in solving it, using all available resources.

I have a general sense of the word I want for that purpose: the opposite of irredeemable, as in, the one trait that makes him irredeemable is tenacity, but flipped in meaning.

Obviously, the direct opposite of irredeemable is redeemable, but instead, redeemable is more of a word to describe a trait that redeems a series of ‘negative’ traits, while I wish it to describe a singularly excellent trait, similar to how irredeemable refers to a singularly terrible trait. It also does not have the same dramatic effect of the word irredeemable.

One word I have come across that may be a good fit is ‘virtuous’, but it doesn’t nearly capture that aspect of excellence of a person due to one trait.

Any suggestions of a word that fits the bill? Specifically, a word that completes this sentence while giving a sense of excellence:

> The one trait that makes him _____ is tenacity; he never gives up on a problem, and employs all his resources to solve it.

<sup>*More than one word is also ok, as long as they’re still adjectives. Also, feel free to let me know if there is a better way to word my question and/or title. Thanks!*</sup>

Comment: 'Stubbornness' has a rather large negative connotation. 'Tenacity' is more positive. // 'One of his outstanding qualities is his ...' doesn't suggest that he's a one-trick pony.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth great points, tenacity is indeed better than stubborn, I might change it to be tenacious + resourceful

Comment: Also *persistent*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth changed to tenacious.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin yup, I use that in one of my sentences, it's also a decent alternative to stubborn.

Comment: Are you trying to express that someone does not _require_ redemption ? In which case your expression of 'irredeemable' is the wrong concept altogether. You mean 'non-redeemable' in the sense of not requiring to be involved in being redeemed. It is your own inappropriate concept that is giving you a problem. As you say, the person's virtuosity lies in their tenacity.

Comment: @NigelJ You make a good point, however I was thinking more along the lines of opposite of an irredeemable trait; an irredeemable trait refers to the trait being so bad that it makes the described noun unworthy of redemption. I want to find an adjective that points towards someone's excellence. I will make this more clear in the question post.

Comment: There is  no 'trait' that makes someone redeemable. The ability to redeem lies solely within the Redeemer.

Comment: @NigelJ What about 'redeemable'? (Unless it can be argued that the Redeemer has the power to redeem the irredeemable, but then we'll enter [philosophical territory](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/34387/omnipotence-paradox-defense-and-meinongianism-neo-meinongianism) :)

Comment: The opposite of *irredeemable* is simply *redeemable*, even as you say it is. If you don't want that, I think you need to framing the question differently—especially the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Excel***?

> "*The one trait that makes him **excel** is tenacity; he never gives up on a problem, and employs all his resources to solve it.*"

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/excel):

> to surpass others or be superior in some respect or area

This not only emphasises the singularity of the trait, it also makes that person stand out from the throng.

Comment: I realize this suggestion is quite obvious, but it seems to fit the requirements. Still, is that the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Not sure why people downvoted, seems like a valid answer to me. You also point out how it fits the context. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Both answers seem good to me, picking this one due to it working to describe both the trait and the person.

Answer (score 3):

One word that fits well in that sentence would be ***invaluable***.

"The one trait that makes him ***invaluable*** is his tenacity..."

Its literal meaning is that something is so good that it is impossible to place a value upon it.